# In SpringMVC, after form is submitted, PropertyNotFoundException Encountered

Tags: java, spring-mvc

This is **Controller**.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Register")
public class RegistrationController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(ModelMap model)
    {
        System.out.println("..In showform()..");
        UserBean userbean=new UserBean();
        model.addAttribute("USER", userbean);
        return "Test";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/Register" ,method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(@ModelAttribute("USER") UserBean user)
    {   
            System.out.println("UserDetails are :"+ user.getFirstName());
            System.out.println("UserDetails are :"+ user.getAge());
            return "Success";
    }

}
```

This is **Test.jsp**

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="USER"  action="Register">
<table>

<tr><td>Name</td> <td><form:input path="FirstName"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Age</td> <td><form:input path="Age"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form:form>
```

This is **Success.jsp**

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name :</td>
            <td><core:out value="${USER.FirstName}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Age :</td>
            <td><core:out value="${USER.Age}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

And this is the `com.beans.UserBean`

```
public class UserBean {

    private String FirstName;

    private int Age;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return Age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.Age = age;
    }
}
```

Now after i Clik on SUBMIT button the following error is Encountered. Dont know why. I have the proper getter/setters in the form backing bean.

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'FirstName' not found on type com.beans.UserBean
```

Comment: rename you property to `firstName` with lower `f`. because of namening convention and try again (also in jsp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getter method `public String getFirstName()` is the equivalent for a instance variable named: `firstName` not `FirstName`.

Since variables starting with lowercase is a [Java convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414001/variable-naming-conventions-in-java), Spring MVC will search for instance variables named : `firstName, age` and **NOT** `FirstName, Age`. 
The exception: `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException` is thrown by Spring because he couldn't find any [method accesors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498287/accessor-methods-in-java) for `FirstName` and `Age`.

All you have to do is to change those instance variables names so they may start with a lowercase : `firstName, age`.

Comment: Hi, Daniel. Thanks a lot. That was silly of me, but still the explanation was really good. trying to learn Spring MVC. So, i guess we would discuss quite often.

Answer (score 1):

rename you property to `firstName` with lower f. because of namening convention and try again (also in jsp)

Answer (score 0):

```
    private String FirstName;

    private int Age;
```

This is really a bad practice, define the first character in your variable with lower case. Make it lower case and try again.

Comment: No problem, sorry if I had sounded abit blunt :) CHEERS